# How to load an AudioClip at runtime without the WWW class?

Tags: unity, audio, streaming

I am currently pulling a `.wav` file from an API. I would like to play it at run-time. Currently I need to save the `.wav` file to the `persistentDataPath` and then use the `WWW` class to load an audio clip using the `file://` prefix. It works fine but the docs do mention that the `WWW` class is [obsolete](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html). What other options do I have if I want to avoid the obsolete method group?

I don't **need** to save the file to disk, I am simply doing that at the moment because its fairly safe to save it and then read it back out.

Comment: Which version unity? unitywebrequest has been around a while

Comment: Did you follow the second link on that page, where it says "The UnityWebRequestWWW module implements the legacy WWW lets you communicate with http services.

*It is recommended to use UnityWebRequest directly for new code.*"?

Comment: @DMGregory UnityWebRequest has no methods to load AudioClip data at run-time, nor does it provide any examples for loading a file from disk. Care to elaborate on how that would work?

Comment: [This looks like a method to load AudioClip data at runtime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.DownloadHandlerAudioClip.html), and [this looks like a shortcut for the same](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip.html).

Comment: @DMGregory I'll have a look at that over the weekend. As I already have the file in memory from a HttpClient call (I need to use this sadly) I might not be able to use a UnityWebRequest but I might be able to use a download handler to pull out the resulting file anyway. Cheers.